# Find the average time (adjust to 2 decimal places) and the total time

Tags: mysql

I need to create a mysql query that shows the average sentence time of all prisoners (adjusted to 2 decimal places) and the total time of their sentences.

```
SELECT ROUND(avg(Sentenced),2) AS Average_Years, sum (Sentenced) AS Total_Years
FROM tblPrisoners;
```

I get an error saying "FUNCTION databasename.sum does not exist"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is caused by the space between function name and parenthesis

```
SUM (Sentenced)
   ^^
```

In Mysql you should not have space between function and parenthesis